# Permissions for user on linux machine to host website

Tags: web-server, permissions, website, chmod

I have root access to my hosted machine. I have created a user account 'abcd' and the user's directory is:

```
/home/abcd/public_html
```

In httpd.conf i have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName abcd.mysite.com
DocumentRoot  /home/abcd/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

This user has a website at that above location. however he cant get his site to upload images into /images folder.

The permissions are:

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

on images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*/home/abcd/public_html/images* is owned by the user and group *abcd*. The web server is running as another user and group (e.g. *apache* or *www-data*). So, can the web server write to that directory?

- d **rwx** rwx r-x : the user permission don't
  apply, since the web server isn't
  running as the user abcd
- d rwx **rwx** r-x : the group permissions don't
  apply, since the web server isn't
  running as the group abcd
- d rwx rwx **r-x** : then the other permissions must apply
  and they do not allow the web server
  to write to it

You might think that the solution is to `chmod o+w /home/abcd/public_html/images`, but that would allow any user to write to images when all you want is to allow the web server to write to it. A better approach would be to change the group that owns the images directory to the group that the web server runs as. Since you're using apache, you should be able to find that group with `ps -o group $(pgrep httpd)`. You can ignore the one process running as root.

If this isn't clear, maybe the wordpress documentation on [changing file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) will help.

Comment: thanks that is helpful. i changed the ownership to apache and it worked, but now the user can't update the files in that folder himself. He normally does an svn update to pull files which go into images/ and elsewhere, but he cant write to that foldr now...

Comment: The wordpress doc says "All files should be owned by your user account on your web server, and should be writable by your username. Files should never be owned by the webserver process itself (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody)."

Comment: I set the ownership as: drwxrwxr-x  5 apache   apache - but he's not able to create a file withing in @sciurus

Comment: Set the user ownership to abcd and the group ownership to apache, e.g. drwxrwxr-x 5 abcd apache